# Is it posible to have multiple user types and customize the home page for the users in Social Engine

Tags: socialengine

I have a requirement where the site is supposed to have multiple user types and different features for each user. Can I achieve this in Social Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, There is functionality in the socialengine where you can create the multiple user type and also from the default functionality, you can manage.
The user type is 'level_id' in the 'engine4_users' table.